# External keyboard space key acting weird suddenly

Tags: keyboard

The space bar on my external keyboard suddenly started acting weird. Whenever I press it, I get the following arrow symbol:
[image]

Comment: Check the settings of "Fn" keys in the BIOS.

Comment: @N0rbert how do I do this? I found the command `dmidecode` to check BIOS settings but I couldn't find Fn